# DB2 timestamp PHP DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, db2, timestamp

After upgrade to PHP 5.3 my application is returning DB2 columns with Timestamp type as "2010-12-15-10.23.22.716000". 
This is causing problem for PHP DateTime function , as it fails with

> $time = new DateTime("2010-12-15-10.23.22.716000");
>
> Failed to parse time string (2010-12-15-10.23.22.716000) at position 25 (0): Unexpected character

It seems its having a problem with too much accuracy in DB2 timestamp. 
Can I somehow force connection to change timestamp format with it is fetching data into?

I am connecting to database with db2_connect function like this:

> $this->connection = db2_connect ( $config ['dsn'], $config ['username'], $config ['password'] );

**Edit:**
I would like to use solution mentioned below, but its not working for me and on my system (AS400) it runs weird.
I have:
    $timeRec = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d-h.i.s.u',$value);

```
$value = $timeRec->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$value = new DibiDateTime($value);
```

If I do var_dump($value) after ->format, correct string is returned, but if I try feed this string to DibiDateTime, that has:

```
public function __construct($time = 'now', DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL)
{    
    if ($timezone === NULL) {
        parent::__construct($time);
    } 
}
```

then it fails with:

> function format() on a non-object

Even when I checked before with var_dump($timeRec) is proper DateTime object.

Comment: Which PHP date time function? You should add that line(s) of code if you want to make your question more saying. And how do you access the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your function (whichever it is) is choking on the microseconds at the end of your date string. Use the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` function to cope with this using the 'u' microsecond tag. See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d-h.i.s.u', '2010-12-15-10.23.22.716000');
var_dump($time);
```

Output on my system:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2010-12-15 10:23:22' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using PDO and the default timestamp format returned at PHP 8.1 and i5/OS 7.2 meant I had to use the following format (note the "H" for 24 hour)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $table['TIMESTAMPCOL']);
```